# How to freeze mango puree?

Tags: freezing, mango

This last season, I tried freezing mango puree. My google research told I me I can just freeze them as is. But when I thawed them, puree had lost its taste. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have not told us what you did so it would be hard so say what you did wrong.

Comment: @paparazzo - I said I froze them as is meaning I got the mango puree, put it in ziplock bag and put it into freezer.

Answer (score 3):

I usually freeze mango slices in a ziplock (note that it's best to place it in a single layer in the freezer)

[image: courtesy of wikihow.com]

then I let them thaw for a few minutes (3-4 minutes) before I blend them and that's my go-to mango smoothie/puree recipe.

The issue with your method might be that you let it thaw completely for a long time which is not really needed. Another issue could be the freezer bag you used which probably is not airtight, that also could affect the taste.

Comment: I would try this method the next season. I sure am thawing for a long time (hours in fridge)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I freeze fruits:

1. Wash, thoroughly dry and peel your fruit.
2. Remove any bruised or undesirable spots.
3. Cut or slice in small sized pieces. For mangoes, I prefer bite sized pieces as they are easy to blend.
4. Place in a zip-lock or food bag and flatten it out.
5. Wrap aluminium foil on it to prevent freezer burn. Freezer burn is the most common cause of flavour and texture loss.
6. Place it in a freezer bag that is specially designed for freezing. It will prevent any moisture or air from getting in.

It works for me and I never had any problem with loss of flavour. The key thing is to prevent freezer burn.

Comment: Butcher paper is more effective and less costly.

Comment: @paparazzo: I've never seen butcher paper in UK supermarkets. It's probably what we call parchment paper.